# Computing Maximal Orders in Large Number Fields with Sage

Tags: sage

I am writing a program in SAGE that, among other things, has to compute maximal orders for "large" number fields. The number fields I am dealing do not only have a fairly large degree (around 40 for those I had to deal with so far), but also very large discriminant. 
Unfortunately, this makes it impossible to use the standard, built-in functions, that SAGE uses to compute maximal orders - the command `K.maximal_order()` is simply too time-expensive. Let me be specific about the notations used in the code below:
Qa12 designates a number field with ring of integers (i.e. maximal order) `OO`. What needs to be computed is the maximal order, written `OOK`, of the extension `K` of `Qa12`.
Now, in MAGMA, this can be done using the following code:

```
subOrderK:=ext<OO | y^2-kappa12>;
subOrderK:=AbsoluteOrder(subOrderK);
D:=Discriminant(subOrderK);
for p in PrimeDivisors(D) do
    subOrderK:=pMaximalOrder(subOrderK,p);
end for;
OOK:=subOrderK;
```

This runs in a fairly short amount of time, i.e. less than a minute in general.
I did not find a way to translate this directly, as there does not seem to be analog of the first two lines of code in SAGE. It could well be that I am missing something, so if you think that you do know a way to translate those first two lines, then please tell me.
If one computes the extension of the field instead, the code should look something like this:

```
K.<c> = Qa12.extension(y^2-kappa12)
K.<alpha> = K.absolute_field()
subOrderK = K.order(alpha)
D = subOrderK.discriminant()
for p in factor(D):
    subOrderK = K.maximal_order(p[0])
OOK = subOrderK
```

Now, there are two problems with this code, the first of which is that the discriminant of said number field being huge, factorising it is impossible. In other words, I have not yet tested the for-loop. Do you see any way of avoiding having to deal with these huge discriminants? The for-loop is the second place I am insecure about: As there is (again - as far as I know) no direct analog to the MAGMA-command `pMaximalOrder(subOrderK,p)`above, I was hoping that SAGE would "remember" the previous value of `subOrderK` in the for-loop, hence recreating the effect of the MAGMA-command. Is this indeed the case? If note, do you see a way to avoid this issue?

NOTE: 
I have posted essentially the same question on ask.sagemath a few days ago, to no avail so far.

Comment: The ask.sagemath link is [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1652/computing-maximal-orders-in-relative-extensions).